# Responsive web design - doing it the right way

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm not sure where to ask this question since there is no code related. I'm really tempted to buy this book so I can become a better mobile developer. What are your thoughts about this book? It's the Smashing Book 5 - Real Life Responsive Web Design http://media.mediatemple.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Smashing-Book-5-1200px1.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, as far as I understand, this kind of question does not belong on SE, so moderators might flag as off-topic.

But if it helps you, here is my answer anyway: 
I have exactly this book on my  kindle and have nothing negative to say about it. I can not compare with similar books but I also have the Web Design eBook Bundle and would say that Smashing are generally doing a solid job with their books. Not sure if true, but I have the feeling their authors are a bit more up-to-date with current design trends and practises.

I would *not* recommend buying the hard cover version. For one, because of the price but also because it is extremely handy to be able to search for stuff inside the book. You'll do that many times. You might also want to copy bits of code from the book from time to time. It contains numerous code examples. Oh and I am sure you do not want to carry 584 pages around if you want to read it somewhere else.

Comment: That is very helpful! Thank you so much!